# SQL Calculated Field

Tags: sql, mysql, calculated-field

I'm creating a view as such:

```
CREATE VIEW all AS
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.description, m.date, m.views, r.rating, r.id
FROM riv_montage m, riv_ratings r
```

But I'd like to create a calculated field **on each row** that does something like:

```
r.rating/COUNT(r.id)
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why are you doing a cross join?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, thanks.

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.description, m.date, m.views,
(SELECT SUM(rating) FROM riv_ratings WHERE id = m.id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM riv_ratings WHERE id = m.id) AS calc
FROM riv_montage m
```

Performance wise it is awful, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say anything about it's performance:

```
CREATE VIEW all 
AS 
SELECT 
    r.rating, r.id, r.rating / (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM riv_ratings) 
FROM  
    riv_ratings r
```